# C# write chars to 2-dimensional array more efficiently

Tags: c#

I have a text string of 120 characters. I want to make 2-dimensional char array, 6 lines with 20 characters. I wonder if i could do this more efficiently, using less variables? Thanks.

Loop:

```
int i = 0, u = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < 120; x++)
{
    array[i, u] = text[x];

    u++;

    if (u == 19)
    {
        i++;
        u = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```
int numRows = 6;
int numCols = 20;
for (int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < numRows; rowIdx++)
{
    for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < numCols; colIdx++)
    {
        array[rowIdx, colIdx] = text[rowIdx * numCols + colIdx];
    }
}
```

Comment: Still wrong, I'm afraid.  It should be `rowIdx * 20 + colIdx`, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You might use ToCharArray method and only one loop:

```
char [][] array = new char[6][];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    array[i] = text.Substring(i * 20, 20).ToCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In .Net jagged arrays are a bit more efficient than rectangular arrays because of the bounds checking.

```
var s = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => i + "123456789 123456789"));

var a = new char[][] { s.ToCharArray(0, 20), s.ToCharArray(20, 20), s.ToCharArray(40, 20), 
                     s.ToCharArray(60, 20), s.ToCharArray(80, 20), s.ToCharArray(100, 20) };

// or a bit less efficient LINQ version
char[][] arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(i => s.ToCharArray(i * 20, 20)).ToArray();
```